# Recommendation for a SQL server development and management tool

Tags: database, sql-server

I am currently using Toad for SQL server 6.8 and I am very disappointed in the quality of the software. It took them more than year to deliver version 6.8 and finally, when they did, it is pretty much unusable. See this [thread](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/f/14/t/34265).

Having said that, Toad for SQL server has some nice features:

1. Data export to excel or sql scripts
2. Ability to view hierarchical data through their master/detail reports which rely on DataExpress grids
3. Data Comparer
4. Structure comparer and ability to generate diff scripts
5. Ability to generate sql based on the table structure.

There are others as well.

I have a love/hate relationship with Toad. The time has come to renew the subscription and I am hesitating to renew.

Can you recommend another tool that at least has the features above?

Thanks